# How to divide a number into multiple parts(not equal) so that there sum is equal to input?

Tags: algorithm

I want to divide a number e.g. input number i.e. 40 into different token(30 parts) numbers randomly selected from a range  and their sum must be equal to input number i.e 40. 
**Edit:**
Max Range is should be 40% and minimum should be 0.

**example:**

```
range = (0,4)

1+1+0+1+1+0+3+0+3+0+0+2+0+4+4+1+1+0+1+1+0+3+0+4+0+2+2+0+4+1 = 40.
```

Actually in real world Showing results for scenario I am having a sum of product users expressions which i need to populate randomly into a record set for each day in last month. I am using php but unable to get the algorithm to process such situation.

Comment: can you please add addition info on constants of the algorithm for example is range within a limit? is input number always greater than tokens? define your problem so we can help

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code!

Answer (score 2):

Simple approach exploits "trial and error" method. Suitable for reasonable small input values.

Note - it might work long time when `n` is close to `p*maxx`. If such case is possible, it would more wise to distribute "holes" rather than "ones" (the second code)

```
import random

def randparts(n, p, maxx):
    lst = [0] * p
    while n > 0:
        r = random.randrange(p)
        if lst[r] < maxx:
            n -= 1
            lst[r] += 1
    return lst

print(randparts(20, 10, 4))

>>>  [2, 0, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3]
```

---

```
def randparts(n, p, maxx):
    if p * maxx  >=  n * 2:
        lst = [0] * p
        while n > 0:
            r = random.randrange(p)
            if lst[r] < maxx:
                n -= 1
                lst[r] += 1
    else:
        lst = [maxx] * p
        n = maxx * p - n
        while n > 0:
            r = random.randrange(p)
            if lst[r] > 0:
                n -= 1
                lst[r] -= 1
    return lst

print(randparts(16, 10, 4))
print(randparts(32, 10, 4))

>> [2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2]
>> [3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 3, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that it is for 'a record set for each day in last month', I assume that the number of tokens could also be 28, or 31, and since you said 'randomly', here is what I would do:

```
1. create a function that takes in:
    a. The number to sum to (40 in your example).
    b. The maximum number of a single token (4 in your example).
    c. The number of tokens (30 in your example).
2. Within the function, create an array the size of the number of tokens (28, 30, 31, or whatever)
3. Initialize all elements of the array to zero.
4. Check to make sure that it is possible to achieve the sum given the maximum single token value and number of tokens.
5. While I need to increment a token (sum > 0):
    a. Select a random token.
    b. Determine if the value of the token can be incremented without going over the max single token value.
    c. If it can, then increment the token value and decrement the sum.
    d. If the token cannot be incremented, then go back to 5a.
6. Return the array of tokens, or however you want them back (you didn't specify).
```

Here is an example in c#:

```
public int[] SegmentSum(int sum, int maxPart, int parts)
{
    if (sum < 0 || maxPart < 0 || parts < 0 || parts * maxPart < sum)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException;

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[] tokens = Enumerable.Repeat(0, parts).ToArray();

    while(sum > 0)
    {
        int token = rnd.Next(parts);
        if (tokens[token] < maxPart)
        {
            tokens[token]++;
            sum--;
        }
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Hope this helps you.